# Why am I getting unexplained vertical lines in the center of merged cells?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, formatting, conditional-formatting

I am working on a spreadsheet that merges 20 columns into a single row. This row is conditionally formatted to display a data bar, of a proportional length based on a set of values from 0 to 275 that appear as values in the merged cell.

I have cells that contain a dotted vertical line in the middle of the merged cell. There are a few behaviors and conditions that I've noticed about the cell. 1.) ALL data elements between 0 and 275 display a bar proportioned for 275 (maximum). Data values OVER 275 will force all the other bars to display proportional to it, which is at the maximum level possible.

I've verified that the formulae, formatting, conditional formatting, and data types are consistent among the cells in the column. I have verified that excel is recognizing the merged cell as a single cell...both by watching the column counter when I move between cells, and by the fact that the 3px "you are here" box surrounds the whole, merged cell for the row in question. One thing that IS consistent between all the cells is that they each fall on the rows for the last days of a months. I am incorporating a total by reference on another worksheet...I'm not sure if this is some sort of "last row of a total" marker, and the bar width represents a total for the month instead of an individual value for the day--which is what I want.

Anyone know what's going on here and how to fix it

Consider:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes merged cell borders are buggy. Though I have not encountered this particular behavior, try one of the following:

1. Unmerge the cell in question, and for the two cells in between which the border appears, remove the left border of the right cell, the right border of the left cell and the middle border of both cells when selected. Then merge them again.
2. Simply copy the row from above, overwriting all the settings (e.g. select the affected merged cell and use *Fill down* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>), which copies the above cell.

HTH!

Comment: Well, that was strange. Even though I'd cut-and-paste (Ctrl-C + Ctrl-V) prior cells into the wonky one (which I tend to do instead of Ctrl-D), that didn't work. Ctrl-D fixed the problem immediately...for both the wonky border and the bar graphing. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, sometimes the merged cell borders are really strange. Glad it worked!

Answer (score 0):

select the cell then go to "conditional formatting" and click on "Clear Rules" then "Clear Rules from selected cells"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).